# Using Google Maps API to geocode NYC high schools by BN code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am trying to geocode NYC high schools by using the Maps Geocoding API and the unique BN code assigned to each high school. For example, typing K733 into Google Maps results in a marker on MESA Charter High School in Brooklyn, NY. However, when I use the API url like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=K733
```

I keep getting "ZERO_RESULTS". I've also tried using the Places API and I've gotten the same results. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it even possible to pull this information from Google Maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not possible to use unique BN codes for Maps Geocoding API because the address component requires [postal address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding)

> address — The street address that you want to geocode, in the format
>   used by the national postal service of the country concerned.
>   Additional address elements such as business names and unit, suite or
>   floor numbers should be avoided. Please refer to the FAQ for
>   additional guidance.